# Copy certain cells and paste them into the next available row

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to copy the data from certain cells in sheet 2 into the next available blank row in sheet 4.
The order that the cells are copying is the order that I want them to paste into the row.

When I press my button the contents "flashes" to suggest it has copied and then clears from the correct cells I have asked for in my code.

However only one value is pasting into the first cell.

I have taken this code from another sheet that I created, however my first sheet only had one range that it was copying from so this worked as expected.

Now I have added extra ranges it is not.

This is my code.

````
Sub CopyPaste()

Range("T15").Copy
Range("T13").Copy
Range("B16").Copy
Range("D16").Copy
Range("F16").Copy
Range("H16").Copy
Range("J16").Copy
Range("L16").Copy
Range("N16").Copy
Range("P16").Copy
Range("R16").Copy

Sheets("Collated Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("B2:S2").ClearContents
Range("B3:S3").ClearContents
Range("B5:S5").ClearContents
Range("B6:S6").ClearContents
Range("B8:S8").ClearContents
Range("B9:S9").ClearContents
Range("B12:S12").ClearContents


    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("A1").Select
   
   End Sub```

Thank you
````

Comment: Copy then immediately paste each range. Or use an array.

Comment: Great thanks seems so obvious now.

Comment: Is the code in the workbook containing these sheets? `Sheet4` is named `Collated Data`. What's the (tab) name of `Sheet2`?